# changing the variations changes all prices woocommerce shop page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have here a jquery script which I am currently using

```
jQuery(document).on("woocommerce_variation_has_changed",".variations_form",function(){
        var price=jQuery(".single_variation").find(".amount").html();
        jQuery(".price").html(price);
    });
```

my variations is located on the shop page and everytime I change the variations the price change exactly but it affects all products

how could I make this affect to only that particular product on the shop page

please help me, I am not good with this. thanks

Comment: can you please add your html markup or please provide a link of the page.

Comment: Your class selectors will select everything with a matching class. You probably need to be more specific. What exactly are you attempting? There is possibly a better/alternate way. Currently, this seems like a jquery question and not WooCommerce-specific.